# Calling Protected API Routes from Laravel Vue.js or React.js MPA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I am building a Laravel Vue MPA Project using Laravel Default Authentication where most of the pages are served by Laravel. But for Form submission I am using Vue Component and the form is directly submitted to the API route. Each Page of Mine contains several vue component. An example is given below

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
                    <profile-component>
                    </profile-component>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

The Problem I am facing is to access protected API routes. For API Authentication I have used Laravel Passport. In the above example if I try to update profile I will have to send Passport Token As well. I read many articles saying not to store auth token in localStorage thats why I tried to use Laravel Secure Cookie. But the problem is I can not access the secure cookie from vuejs then how I can send my token In vuejs API call.

I have also tried to store it into database user table and tried to pass token through props but feeling like it is not safe to pass it as props.

Now I couldn't understand what to do. should I use localStorage or there is any other better way of doing this.

Thanks in advance if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a library like Axios to make your API requests from Vuejs. With it, you can include the `withCredentials` option in the request, which will automatically use your API token:

```
axios.get('some api url', {withCredentials: true});
```

You can also set the parameter globally when creating the Axios instance:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const instance = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true
})
```

Comment: Is this going to add token in Authorization header or as cookie?